# Setting Up Global Sass variables

Tags: css, sass, directory, global

I have a file called `_colors.scss` which has the following:

```
$base-vwhite: #ffffff;
$base-brand: #9ea70f;
```

This is imported in a file called `utilities`:

```
@import 'colors.scss';
```

I have a scss called `components.scss` which imports all the component styles:

```
@import 'menu.scss';
```

component.scss and utilities.scss are added to `main.scss`

```
@import 'utilities/utilities.scss';
@import 'components/components.scss';
```

My problem arises when the menu.scss tries to call a color variable:

```
.menu{
  background-color: $base-brand; 
}
```

I get the error:Undefined variable: "$base-brand;".

How do I need to set the colors variable so it can be used by all nested components and directories?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a `.scss` file extension for the utilities file?  Provided it's imported before the variables are used, should work.

Comment: @kyranjamie I am, i'll update my question

Comment: You should import the "colors" variables into `main.scss`. I think you're getting the variables after they're needed. I've noticed that order can confuse compilers.

Comment: @BryceHowitson that worked thanks.